Change background of part of GoHighLevel form
I built [this][1] form in GoHighLevel. I am trying to adjust the background so the top part (before the form fields, header and description text) is white, and the rest a green.
I add the following code to the custom css section of the form settings but it doesn't work:


background: linear-gradient(transparent 40%, #415024 40%) no-repeat !important;



Given that I want the background changes applied to the whole form I did not indicate a selector, but even trying various selectors the changes are not applied. What changes do I need to make to the css?
[1]: https://api.leadconnectorhq.com/widget/form/Jd1fNyUWJVhTuphrEPtt?notrack=true

Your #_builder-form div has the following CSS property which is being applied with priority over your linear-gradient:
background-color: #435126FF;

In the code you provided, I see you included !important, but in the CSS of your page that is not actually present. If you were to go back and add the !important to the end of your linear-gradient, then that will also fix your problem.
